# Java NoClassDefFoundError trying to run Tinyviz on Tinyos Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, java, tinyos

I have a problem with Tinyviz, which is a Java simulator. When I run it with the command `tinyviz`, I get this message on my screen:

```
java -Dpython.cachedir=/tmp/jython.cache -DDBG= -DSIMDBG= 
net.tinyos.sim.SimDriver -gui Starting SimDriver... 
Simulation random seed 1486964521 Initializing simulator objects... 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/tinyos/packet/Platform 
at net.tinyos.message.MessageFactory.instantiateTOSMsg(MessageFactory.java:122) 
at net.tinyos.message.MessageFactory.createTOSMsg(MessageFactory.java:44) 
at net.tinyos.sim.SimCommands.(SimCommands.java:64) 
at net.tinyos.sim.SimDriver.(SimDriver.java:244) 
at net.tinyos.sim.SimDriver.main(SimDriver.java:539) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.tinyos.packet.Platform 
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366) 
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355) 
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354) 
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423) at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308) 
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356) ... 5 more
```

Comment: Do you have the source code for this?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking this kind of error is caused by the Java `CLASSPATH` not being set correctly.

Most software will come with instructions or a shell script or an installer as to how to set it. If not try setting that variable to the base directory containing `.class` files, or to the location of the jar file.